# LightGallery Dailymotion

Tags: video, lightgallery

I use LightGallery (https://github.com/sachinchoolur/lightGallery) for my website and I need to show some dailymotion videos.

This plugin works fine with youtube/vimeo, but I get nothing from a dailymotion videos.

To show this I use a loop with this code as a `dynamicEl:[]`:

```
{"src":"<?php print 'http://www.dailymotion.com/video/'.$dailymotion['safe_value']; ?>","thumb":"<?php print 'http://www.dailymotion.com/thumbnail/video/'.$dailymotion['safe_value']; ?>"},
```

Same code as I do with youtube (and it work):

```
{"src":"<?php print 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v='.$youtube['safe_value']; ?>","thumb":"<?php print 'http://img.youtube.com/vi/'.$youtube['safe_value'].'/0.jpg'; ?>"},
```

FYI I have version 1.2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem would be solved if you use the original markup with the possibility to share iFrames,
Here is the basic structure for your HTML:

`<div id="lightgallery" data-iframe="true" data-src="'.$videoSRC.'">
    <a href="'.$ThumbnailURL.'">
</div>`

- data-iframe="true" --> It is used when you want to use an iFrame(like ones dailymotion provide)
- $videoSRC --> This one has your video's URL --> To obtain it, go to http://www.dailymotion.com/ select a video then click on export link to get an iframe code. Suppose you have something like this:

  iframe frameborder="0" width="480" height="270"    src="//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x3ouf29" allowfullscreen

*sorry this iFrame code is messy, I can not pate a full code in stack overflow.
copy the src value so in our example:

```
$videoSRC='http://www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/x3ouf29';
```

$ThumbnailURL --> if you want to show a thumbnail for your video link, this is the place you enter its URL.

Hope this helps, it seems to be a little bit late.